# c++ example of non-local static objects interacting in different translation units

Tags: c++, static, initialization

I am reading Scott Meyer's Effective C++ book. In it, he mentions that the relative order of non-local static objects in different translation units is undefined. To demonstrate, he gave the following example. In one file,

```
class FileSystem {
   public: 
   std::size_t numDisks() const;
};
extern FileSystem tfs;
```

In another file,

```
class Directory {
  public:
  Director() {
    std::size_t disks = tfs.numDisks();
  }
};
Directory tempDir();
```

I understand why this could be bad if the initialization order is indeterminate, since `tfs` may not be initialized before `tempDir` calls its constructor.

However, I don't understand why the initialization order is indeterminate; in particular, why there are two translation units. For `tfs` to be used in the second file, wouldn't the first one have to be included, hence putting both files in the same translation unit?

So my question: What's wrong with what I just said, or what's another example of static non-local objects interacting in different translation units which can cause problems due to initialization order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that in the first file, there's only a declaration of `tfs`, not its definition (it's using the `extern` keyword).

This implies that `tfs` is defined in a different translation unit, hence the unspecified initialisation order.